# How to change selected item text in list box at run time?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, listbox

I tried with code like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Leave
  ' This way is not working
  ListBox1.SelectedItem = TextBox1.Text
  ' This is not working too
  ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

The form is looked like this:

[image]

I need to change that list text while user typing in the text box. Is it possible to do that at run time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the form's leave event `MyBase.Leave`, so when it fires, it is useless to you.

Try using the TextChanged event of the TextBox instead.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                 Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
```

Make sure to check if an item is actually selected in the ListBox:

```
If ListBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
  ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) = TextBox1.Text
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Double click to select line (item) inside list box and change or modify.
Instead of using text box use `ListBox1_MouseDoubleClick` event

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDoubleClick
```

then add this code inside this event

```
Dim intIndex As Integer = ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
Dim objInputBox As Object = InputBox("Change Item :","Edit", ListBox1.SelectedItem)
If Not objInputBox = Nothing Then
    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    ListBox1.Items.Insert(intIndex, objInputBox)
End If
```

OR

```
Dim objInputBox As Object = InputBox("Change Item :","Edit", ListBox1.SelectedItem)
If Not objInputBox = Nothing Then
   ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) = objInputBox 
End If
```